# twitter oauth callback not called after successful signin

Tags: java, twitter, callback, twitter-oauth, auth-token

I'm performing twitter oauth authentication but the callback isn't being called
(set as http://www.kdcappfactory.com/twittersuccess/success in app settings)

here's what I do:

request a token from

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>
> authorizationHeaderValue: OAuth
>   oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kdcappfactory.com%2Ftwittersuccess%2Fsuccess",
>   oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_nonce="3f8f63af799b21c0",
>   oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxxx%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   oauth_timestamp="1392188696", oauth_version="1.0"

I get this response:

oauth_token=ciOUBwIhJOD76Vt0kONCfq8qRja8jvjoasfd8itmQcE&oauth_token_secret=lYg4IvebXNwqA4aAUR48e11g6O4YggZJQjxtBBEVY&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

I open the URL using oauth_token

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=ciOUBwIhJOD76Vt0kONCfq8qRja8jvjoasfd8itmQcE

and listen for a redirection to http://www.kdcappfactory.com/twittersuccess/success

but after successful login the user isn't redirected,

I still get a signin and cancel button
and the signin button takes me nowhere, cancel takes me to another page asking me to exit the application, this redirects me to the success url with a "denied" param added to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the redirection endpoint was incorrect

Correct
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

Was using 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate